# What is the sum of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(zn+1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, gamma-function

I need to find the value of the following series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(zn+1)^2}$$
I know there is a nice closed form in terms of trigamma functions, as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BDivide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2841%29%2Ck%5D%2CPower%5B%5C%2840%294k%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2Cinf%7D%5D), I simply can't get it.

What I know is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+n)^2}=\psi_1(z)$$
and
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{zn+1}=\frac{1}{2z}\left[\psi_0\left(\frac{z+1}{2z}\right)-\psi_0\left(\frac{1}{2z}\right)\right]$$
In particular, differentiating this last series w.r.t $z$ doesn't help, since you get an $n$ in the numerator as well. How to proceed?

Comment: Calculate $z^{-2}\psi_1(z^{-1})$. What do you get?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz I get the required series, but without the alternating sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find the answer by breaking n into even and odd numbers
$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_{2n}+a_{2n+1})$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(zn+1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^{(2n)}}{(z(2n)+1)^2}+\frac{(-1)^{(2n+1)}}{(z(2n+1)+1)^2)}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(2nz+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(2nz+z+1)^2}\right)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(2z)^2}\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{2z})^2}-\frac{1}{(2z)^2}\frac{1}{(n+\frac{z+1}{2z})^2}\right)$$
The sum obviously can be evaluated using the trigamma function

Answer (score 3):

> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{zn+1}=\frac{1}{2z}\left[\psi_0\left(\frac{z+1}{2z}\right)-\psi_0\left(\frac{1}{2z}\right)\right]$$

Take derivative works,

$$\begin{align}\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{zn+1}&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nn}{(zn+1)^2}=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(n+\frac1z-\frac1z)}{(zn+1)^2}\\
\\
&=-\frac1z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{zn+1}+\frac1z\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(zn+1)^2}\end{align}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: This is a very interesting approach, thank you

Comment: This is a much more creative method

Answer (score 1):

Here is an integral representation.

Let $|x|<1$. Write
$$f_z(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}x^{zn}=\frac{1}{1-x^z}.$$
Then
$$\int_0^tf_z(y)=\int_0^1 tf_z(ty)dy=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{t^{zn+1}}{zn+1}.$$
Dividing by $t$ and integrating again,
$$\int_0^x\int_0^1f_z(ty)dydt=\int_0^1\int_0^1xf_z(xty)dydt=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{x^{zn+1}}{(zn+1)^2}.$$
Thus
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1f_z((-1)^{1/z}yt)dydt=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dydt}{1+(yt)^z}=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(zn+1)^2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using only that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(z+n)^2}=\psi_1(z)\tag1
$$
we can derive
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(nz+1)^2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{(2nz+1)^2}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(zn+1)^2}\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac1{2z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(n+\frac1{2z}\right)^2}-\frac1{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{\left(n+\frac1z\right)^2}\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac1{2z^2}\psi_1\!\left(\frac1{2z}\right)-\frac1{z^2}\psi_1\!\left(\frac1z\right)\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ the alternating sum is twice the sum of the even terms
$\phantom{\text{(2a):}}$ minus the sum of all the terms
$\text{(2b):}$ factor common pieces out of each sum
$\text{(2c):}$ apply $(1)$